# Do AWS instances raise events that can directed onto SNS/SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have several workflows in xaml that detach instances from load balancers, backup databases etc. currently this involves polling via a rest api to check the status of an instance or RDS or example. We would prefer to subscribe to a SNS topic and get notified via a message when the state of an instance changes. Any guidance on how to setup something like this up appreciated

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using autoscaling, the new AutoScaling Lifecycle Management events sound like exactly what you want:
http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-update-lifecycle-standby-detach/

You can configure SNS or SQS notifications when servers are added or removed from your autoscaling groups.